# How to hide email headers info like X-me and Received?

Tags: email, smtp, email-headers, email-spam, bulk-email

in my inbox i see that some emails have a pretty header that won't let us get much info about the sender
as exemple :

```
From: Boutique Fr<service@boutique.com>

Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 06:32:11 +0600

Subject: Important Deals

Message-Id: <LTR24WPEGBU4.68WKQS4JGNEG3@DESKTOP-P7IQ74L>

To: Me <joevenner@wanadoo.fr>

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Id: <LTR24WPEGBU4.ZETAYO6VGZMG@DESKTOP-P7IQ74L>
```

but when i tried to send my smtp emails, after i checked the header i have many info that shows many infos about me, as the **ServerIP** and the **X-me-Spamscore**

I want to know if there is a way to hide those info or to make my header look a little bit as the one above

my Header [ill hide my info with **] :

```
Return-Path: <no-reply@******c.***>

Received: from mwinf5c69 (mwinf5c69 [10.223.111.119])
by mwinb2h05 with LMTPA;
Thu, 20 Aug 2020 16:55:18 +0200

X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3

Received: from server.localdomain ([89.20*.1**.*9])
by mwinf5c69 with ME
id HqvH2300114RfSH01qvHsl; Thu, 20 Aug 2020 16:55:18 +0200

X-bcc: *********@wanadoo.fr

X-ME-bounce-domain: wanadoo.fr

X-ME-engine: default

X-me-spamcause: (70)(0000)gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrgeduiedruddutddgheeiucetufdoteggodetrfdotffvucfrrhhofhhilhgvmecuoffgpdggtffipffknecuuegrihhl
ohhuthemucegtddtnecufghrlhcuvffnffculdejtddmnecujfgurhepggffhffvuffkgihotgfgsehtjehjtddttddvnecuhfhrohhmpefgmhhilhihucdqucetmhgrii
honhgvucevlhhivghnthcuufgvrhhvihgtvgcuoehnohdqrhgvphhlhiesvggtohhlohhophgtrdighiiiqeenucggtffrrghtthgvrhhnpeevgedufefhffeuhfdugeek
teevheejlefggeehveekgeeuheeuffekjeefheefueenucfkphepkeelrddvtdekrdduleeirdegleenucevlhhushhtvghrufhiiigvpedtnecurfgrrhgrmhephhgvlh
hopehsvghrvhgvrhdrlhhotggrlhguohhmrghinhdpihhnvghtpeekledrvddtkedrudeliedrgeelpdhmrghilhhfrhhomhepnhhoqdhrvghplhihsegvtgholhhoohhp
tgdrgiihiidprhgtphhtthhopehmhhhorhhrvghnthesfigrnhgrughoohdrfhhr

X-me-spamlevel: not-spam

X-ME-Helo: server.localdomain

X-ME-IP: 89.20*.1**.*9

X-ME-Entity: ofr

Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by server.localdomain (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 9CE8217B
for <*******@wanadoo.fr>; Thu, 20 Aug 2020 14:55:16 +0000 (UTC)

Mime-Version: 1.0

Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 15:55:16 +0100

From: Emily - Client Service <no-reply@*****c.com>

To: mh <********@wanadoo.fr>

Subject: Test

Message-ID: <ae7abf911c0e616bba7a856327072a01@ecoloopc.xyz>

X-Sender: no-reply@ecoloopc.xyz

Organization: ecoloopc.xyz

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
format=flowed

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```